# Reactjs - how can i make line break in template strings and return for rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

You need to display the following content formatted on the screen:

```
divs:
 <div>my text</div> <div>my text</div>
```

i tried to do this, but everything came out without line break:

```
 const HtmlCreator=()=>{
           let text="my text";
           return (`divs: \n <div>${text}</div> <div>${text}</div> `)
        {
    return (
    <div>
       <p><HtmlCreator/></p>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: does my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `whiteSpace:'pre'` to your style :

```
<p style={{whiteSpace:'pre'}}><HtmlCreator /></p>
```

this is useful when you cannot modify the original data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<br />`, but you'll need a wrapper. For that, you can use [`<React.Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const HtmlCreator = () => {
  let text = "my text";

  return (
    <Fragment>
      divs
      <br />
      {`<div>${text}</div> <div>${text}</div>`}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-johnson-l308e)

Your question implies you'd like to show the HTML itself (escape it) and not render it. If you meant the latter, you could do:

```
const HtmlCreator = () => {
  let text = "my text";

  return (
    <Fragment>
      divs
      <br />
      <div>{text}</div>
      <div>{text}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-lake-ejp1f)